# LinkedHashMap with methods to access inner Linked List

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons, linkedhashmap

I need to access the inner `LinkedList` inside of a `LinkedHashMap`. I want to be able to access both the tail and the head. Through the iterator, I can only access either the head or the tail, depending on the access order used at construction.

How can I efficiently access head and tail of the inner list in *O(1)*?

The idea is similar to Apache Common Collection's `LinkedHashMap.asList()` (but I'd like to avoid adding Apache Commons Collections as a dependency, as I already have Guava).

Comment: I'm going to guess that you can't.

Comment: Nope, can't be done.  Could you explain why you want to?  There might be another way to solve your problem that we could suggest.

Comment: [LinkedMap](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/collections/collections-generic/4.01/collections-generic-4.01-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/commons/collections15/map/LinkedMap.html) is probably the best bet. Guava's ImmutableMap is ordered and returns ImmutableSet for keySet(), which has an atList() view. So it could be done, but a little indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the inner LinkedList only via reflection.

With reflection you can access private members by using `setAccessible(true)`
This may fail when the javas Security manager has disabled private access via reflection.

Another solution would be using an open source implemenetation of a LinkedHashMap and then add a getter to the internal list.